# Gitlab CI/CD changes doesn't work as expected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have `only:changes` to trigger job after changes in specific directory (packages/demo):

```
.demo: &demo
  only:
    changes:
      - packages/demo/**/*
demojob:
  <<: *demo  
  stage: test 
  script:
    - echo demo
```

Should run when some file in `packages/demo` is edited.

But job is fired sometimes wrong I edited file in `packages/car/demo.txt` and it trigged `demojob` job. Why? What is wrong?

**I pushed a new branch, maybe its connected to push of new branch.**

Answer (score 0):

You are right. For what I know, the "only: changes" feature work by comparing the current commit to the last one on the same branch. Since you are pushing to a new ref, the new commit has nothing to compare to, so the "only: changes" return True and the job is created. This is explicited [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-onlychanges-without-pipelines-for-merge-requests) :

> When pushing a new branch or a new tag to GitLab, the policy always
> evaluates to true.

To consistantly avoid the creation of the job, you need to specify a branch with "only: refs".